# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) in R - Google Ads clicks

Tags: r, google-analytics

I use R Studio to export the necessary data from the GA4 property. I wanted to collect data on Google Ads campaign name, number of sessions and Google Ads clicks assigned to the corresponding campaigns. The number of sessions downloads to me, but it shows 0 Google Ads clicks, although I can see in the GA4 property that the clicks are there. Have you also had this problem? I am using the publisherAdclicks metric:

[metric in R Studio API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWujF.png)

I have not found any other metric through which I can retrieve this data, so do you have any idea what the problem is?

My code looks like this:

```
googleAdsSessionsClick <- google_analytics_set(c("sessions", "publisherAdClicks"),
                                               c("sessionCampaignName", "sessionSourceMedium"))
```

I use my own function:

```
google_analytics_set <- function(choosenMetrics = NULL, choosenDimentions = NULL) {ga_data(webPropertyId,
                   date_range = date,
                   metrics = choosenMetrics,
                   dimensions = choosenDimentions)}
```

Comment: Did you try sending multiple requests with different set of dimension-metric combinations? Because `sessions` and `publisherAdClicks` are of different scopes and that can result into incorrent response.

Comment: I even tried to export only publisherAdClicks, without other metrics or dimensions and it also didn't work.

Comment: In UA there are two different metrics `ga:adClicks` for Google Ads and `ga:totalPublisherClicks` for linked publisher account (AdSense, AdX, DFP). Looks like in GA4 `adClicks` is not yet available.